# Difference Between: Native DLL, UWP DLLs and C++/CLI DLLs

Tags: c++, visual-c++, dll, uwp, windows-runtime

I am very much aware of what is a vanilla Win32 native DLL (no UWP, no RT, no CLR). I'm also aware of C++/CLI based DLL which are to support the .NET compliant programs written in any language.

What's confusing me is these two UWP DLL types:

- Universal Windows - **C++/CX**
- Universal Windows - **Windows Runtime Component**

When a UWP component-based  DLL is created, it adds (allows) classes to be exported (part of the question is: Are they CLR complaint classes?). Dependency Walker shows that it is linked to some non-standard/non-native DLLs.

When a UWP CX based DLL is created, it just a native DLL. Dependency Walker shows it is linked to Kernel32.DLL etc.

By this, I conclude that:

- C++/CX is a UWP DLL which is similar to native DLL
- Runtime Component UWP DLL is similar to a C++/CLI kind of DLL.

So then what exactly are these two new types of UWP DLLs?

Comment: UWP is native code, it's just a new set of libraries, not available in classic API style. You can use it however in a Win32 app. CX is obsolete in favor of C++/WinRT.

Comment: Kenny Kerr published two excellent articles [Windows with C++ - The Windows Runtime Application Model](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn342867.aspx) and [Windows with C++ - Windows Runtime Components](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt238401.aspx). They will form a solid foundation, and do away with the confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of them are native code. C++/CX shares some syntax with C++/CLI, but it has no ties to .NET. A Windows Runtime Component is a re-usable component that can be called from other applications in any supported language (C++, C#, VB, JavaScript). The other project is just a stand-alone app.

Note that the CLR dependencies are only present in Debug builds (due to some XAML debug dependencies); in Release builds there are no CLR dependencies.